# Adding Text (e.g., Numbers) to Symbols

Tags: symbols

Using `\usym{2776}` one can typeset numbers in circles. Is it possible, to also add numbers to other symbols, e.g., `\faBookmark`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage{utfsym}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}
  
\begin{document}

My text {\relscale{1.1}\usym{2776}} is awesome.

My text {\relscale{.9}\faBookmark} is awesome.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. One way is to write your symbol and then add a number on top of it, for example with `\ooalign`. Here's a possible solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{utfsym}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand*{\faBookmarknum}[1]{%
    \ooalign{%
        \relscale{.9}\faBookmark\cr%
        \hfil\raisebox{.5ex}{%
            \color{white}\relscale{.65}#1%
        }\hfil\cr%
    }%
}
  
\begin{document}

My text {\relscale{1.1}\usym{2776}} is awesome.

My text \faBookmarknum{1} is awesome.

\footnotesize
\faBookmarknum{1}
\faBookmarknum{2}
\faBookmarknum{3}
\faBookmarknum{4}
\faBookmarknum{5}
\faBookmarknum{6}
\faBookmarknum{7}
\faBookmarknum{8}
\faBookmarknum{9}
\faBookmarknum{0}

\normalsize
\faBookmarknum{1}
\faBookmarknum{2}
\faBookmarknum{3}
\faBookmarknum{4}
\faBookmarknum{5}
\faBookmarknum{6}
\faBookmarknum{7}
\faBookmarknum{8}
\faBookmarknum{9}
\faBookmarknum{0}

\large
\faBookmarknum{1}
\faBookmarknum{2}
\faBookmarknum{3}
\faBookmarknum{4}
\faBookmarknum{5}
\faBookmarknum{6}
\faBookmarknum{7}
\faBookmarknum{8}
\faBookmarknum{9}
\faBookmarknum{0}

\Large
\faBookmarknum{1}
\faBookmarknum{2}
\faBookmarknum{3}
\faBookmarknum{4}
\faBookmarknum{5}
\faBookmarknum{6}
\faBookmarknum{7}
\faBookmarknum{8}
\faBookmarknum{9}
\faBookmarknum{0}

\end{document}
```

---

Here's another option were the symbol is lowered instead of the number being raised, so that the baseline of the number aligns with that of the text.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{utfsym}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand*{\faBookmarknum}[1]{%
    \ooalign{%
        \raisebox{-.5ex}{%
            \relscale{.9}\faBookmark%
        }\cr%
        \hfil\textcolor{white}{\relscale{.65}#1}\hfil\cr%
    }%
}
  
\begin{document}

My text {\relscale{1.1}\usym{2776}} is awesome.

My text \faBookmarknum{1} is awesome.

\footnotesize
\faBookmarknum{1}
\faBookmarknum{2}
\faBookmarknum{3}
\faBookmarknum{4}
\faBookmarknum{5}
\faBookmarknum{6}
\faBookmarknum{7}
\faBookmarknum{8}
\faBookmarknum{9}
\faBookmarknum{0}

\normalsize
\faBookmarknum{1}
\faBookmarknum{2}
\faBookmarknum{3}
\faBookmarknum{4}
\faBookmarknum{5}
\faBookmarknum{6}
\faBookmarknum{7}
\faBookmarknum{8}
\faBookmarknum{9}
\faBookmarknum{0}

\large
\faBookmarknum{1}
\faBookmarknum{2}
\faBookmarknum{3}
\faBookmarknum{4}
\faBookmarknum{5}
\faBookmarknum{6}
\faBookmarknum{7}
\faBookmarknum{8}
\faBookmarknum{9}
\faBookmarknum{0}

\Large
\faBookmarknum{1}
\faBookmarknum{2}
\faBookmarknum{3}
\faBookmarknum{4}
\faBookmarknum{5}
\faBookmarknum{6}
\faBookmarknum{7}
\faBookmarknum{8}
\faBookmarknum{9}
\faBookmarknum{0}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not what was asked, but it would look nicer if the baseline of the numbers were positioned at the baseline of the text, and there's room below the baseline where the text descenders would be.  So maybe lowering the symbol instead of raising the number would be possible.

Comment: +1. I would like @barbarabeeton's suggestion too

Comment: @barbarabeeton Good idea, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @user1 I added another solution